# Windows 10 UWP Command Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Since applying the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition along with the SDK, one of the Command Bars has different behavior.  It used to display three AppButtons.  Now, only two will display.  There appears to be an empty button on the far left.

[image: Command Bar]

Here is the XAML:

```
<CommandBar x:Name="VideoGroupCommands"
            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
            Background="{StaticResource LightBeigeBrush}"
            IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsVideoGroupSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Edit"
                  x:Uid="Edit"
                  Label=""
                  Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.EditVideoGroupCommand}"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Delete"
                  x:Uid="Delete"
                  Label=""
                  Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeleteGroupCommand}"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="MoveToFolder" x:Uid="Merge" Label=""/>
</CommandBar>
```

How do I eliminate the gap on the left?

Comment: Did you test your code on PC or mobile? Your image looks like it is in xaml designer, but I can't reproduce your problem on designer or pc or mobile, my os bulid: 14393.

Comment: This is a windows store app (64bit) and I run it on a PC.  While running in Debug or Release mode, I see the gap on the left.  I've tried cleaning my solution too.  I'm glad you tried to reproduce it and cannot.  This means there is probably something I can do to fix it.  I'm going to try to build without the command bar and then put it back in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the update changed the display mechanics, slightly, for the command bar.  To fix this, I changed the grid column the control is in from a FIXED width to an AUTO width.  Now, the control displays all three buttons with no gap on the left.  The column is a little wider, but I can absorb it.

In the picture above, the command bar was cutting the third button out of the display.